# How do I turn on the executable bit in programs from mounted drives?

Tags: security, ntfs

I have Ubuntu 10.10 dual booting with Windows 7. I have a couple of games on the Windows partition, some of which can be run with Wine. The problem is that I can't turn on the executable bit on files from mounted drives. When I go to properties and try to toggle it, it turns back off. I always need to copy said programs to the Ubuntu filesystem, which is annoying.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do the `.exe` files need to be executable? They're not being executed, `wine` is being executed and is loading them. (Just like a Python script doesn't need to be executable if you write `python script.py` or shell: `sh shellscript.sh`)

Comment: @Oli: The exe files are being executed. Wine just provides the OS emulation layer needed to execute the Windows program.

Comment: My .exe files are associated with the wine binary. None are themselves execuable.

Answer (score 2):

Have a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/598023)... (always a good place to start investigating workarounds)

Answer (score 1):

Use the user mapping feature of ntfs-3g; details are in man ntfs-3g (search, using /, for "^user mapping").

Run the ntfs-3g.usermap tool with the Windows partition, which must be unmounted:

```
$ sudo ntfs-3g.usermap /dev/sda1  # sda1 may be different for you
```

It creates a "UserMapping" file in the current directory, move it to your NTFS partition (after mounting):

```
# you may need sudo for these commands
$ mkdir /mount/your-fs-name/.NTFS-3G
$ mv UserMapping /mount/your-fs-name/.NTFS-3G/
```

There is also a [tutorial](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/usermap.html) on user mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Add *exec* to mount options, just be aware that this will set every file as executable (in my understanding). However this worked for me.